# http to https redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I try to achieve the following behavior with .htaccess:

Redirect http://www.mydomain.tld -> **https**://mydomain.tld

Also redirect my old links like:

http://www.mydomain.tld/news/mynews should be redirected to https://mydomain.tld/news/mynews

The page should now only be available over https without the leading "www".

I have this rule to redirect from http://www.mydomain.tld to http://mydomain.tld:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Force https

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Strict-Transport-Security max-age=16070400;
</IfModule>
```

But I have problems to figure out how to correctly write the conditions so that I'm not losing my build up link power (Redirect 301 is important).

Hopefully anyone can help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Your `[R=301,L]` is defining the redirect as a 301. You can test this by just going to the site in a browser with the developer tool's network interface up, inside there it will show any redirects. Related though you should redirect to `https` and not `http` in that rule. Also as a heads up because people miss this alot you should check for *any* subdomain, not just www, and redirect. That way if someone links to nonsense.yourdomain.com it will still redirect and Google won't index your "new" subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I redirect everything to https://example.com without www.

This is what I use:

```
#Redirect www and http
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Never had a problem with it like this.